# Spark save Kafka InputDStream as Json file

Tags: java, json, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I just wondered whether there is a method in Spark, so I can save a JavaInputDStream as a Json file, or generally as any file.
And if not, whether there is an other possibility to save the content of 
a kafka topic as a file in Spark.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you map your `JavaInputDStream` to a `stream` you could do as follow:

```
stream.foreachRDD(rdd -> {
            OffsetRange[] offsetRanges = ((HasOffsetRanges) rdd.rdd()).offsetRanges();

            rdd.mapToPair(new PairFunction<ConsumerRecord<String, String>, String, String>() {
                @Override
                public Tuple2<String, String> call(ConsumerRecord<String, String> record) {
                    return new Tuple2<>(record.key(), record.value());
                }
            }).foreachPartition(partition -> {

                OffsetRange o = offsetRanges[TaskContext.get().partitionId()];
                System.out.println(o.topic() + " " + o.partition() + " " + o.fromOffset() + " " + o.untilOffset());

                if (partition.hasNext()) {

                    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("filename.txt");;
                    out.println(text);

                    try {
                        while (partition.hasNext()) {

                            Tuple2<String, String> message = partition.next();
                            out.println(message);
                        }

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace(
                }

            });
        });
        ssc.start();
        ssc.awaitTermination();
```

Just don't forget that if you have multiple partitions inside your Kafka topic, you are going to write a file per partition following the approach above.

Comment: Thank you very much, this actually helped me.